# MySQL - Want to Minus two SUM() values from two SELECT statements

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to be able to grab the two values that I have generated in SUM() from two SELECT queries and minus these values in order to get the result (OutstandingFunds).

These are my two SELECT queries:

Statement (1):

```
SELECT SUM(Cf.Amount) AS ClearedFunds
FROM (
SELECT Amount FROM PAYMENT1 WHERE `Status` = "Cleared"
UNION ALL
SELECT Amount FROM PAYMENT2 WHERE `Status` = "Cleared"
UNION ALL
SELECT Amount FROM PAYMENT3 WHERE `Status` = "Cleared") AS Cf;
```

Statement (2):

```
SELECT SUM(Price) AS TotalSales
FROM PROPERTY
WHERE Status = “Sold”;
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need to show the separate subtotal for total sales and cleared funds, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT SUM(Total.`Price`) AS ClearedFunds
FROM (
    SELECT `Price` FROM PROPERTY WHERE `Status` = 'Sold'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT (`Amount` * -1) AS `Price` FROM PAYMENT1 WHERE `Status` = 'Cleared'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT (`Amount` * -1) AS `Price` FROM PAYMENT2 WHERE `Status` = 'Cleared'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT (`Amount` * -1) AS `Price` FROM PAYMENT3 WHERE `Status` = 'Cleared'
) AS Total;
```

I am assuming you are wanting to subtract cleared funds from total sales here.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there... here's the working `SQL`:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(Cf.Amount) AS ClearedFunds
FROM (
SELECT Amount FROM PAYMENT1 WHERE `Status` = "Cleared"
UNION ALL
SELECT Amount FROM PAYMENT2 WHERE `Status` = "Cleared"
UNION ALL
SELECT Amount FROM PAYMENT3 WHERE `Status` = "Cleared") as Cf)

- (SELECT SUM(Price) AS TotalSales
FROM PROPERTY
WHERE Status = "Sold") as Result;
```

Here's the SQL Fiddle so that you can play with test data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18677/11

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SELECT ... INTO ...`, in your case:

```
SELECT SUM(Cf.Amount) AS ClearedFunds
FROM (
SELECT Amount FROM PAYMENT1 WHERE `Status` = "Cleared"
UNION ALL
SELECT Amount FROM PAYMENT2 WHERE `Status` = "Cleared"
UNION ALL
SELECT Amount FROM PAYMENT3 WHERE `Status` = "Cleared") INTO @cf;

SELECT SUM(Price) AS TotalSales
FROM PROPERTY
WHERE Status = “Sold” INTO @ts;
```

Then you can substract or use them in any other query, like this:

```
SELECT @ts - @cf;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT C.ClearedFunds - P.TotalSales
FROM (
SELECT SUM(Cf.Amount) AS ClearedFunds
FROM (
SELECT Amount FROM PAYMENT1 WHERE `Status` = "Cleared"
UNION ALL
SELECT Amount FROM PAYMENT2 WHERE `Status` = "Cleared"
UNION ALL
SELECT Amount FROM PAYMENT3 WHERE `Status` = "Cleared") AS Cf) C,
(SELECT SUM(Price) AS TotalSales
FROM PROPERTY
WHERE Status = “Sold”) P  
;
```